# How to pass a Javascript ID value into a form Placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, query-string

I have used a function to capture the Query String value of "name" - i.e. imagine a party invite site;

https://cometomyparty.com?name=phil

The function used is;

```
script type="text/javascript">
     function getQuerystring(){
     var q=document.location.toString();
     q=q.split("?");
     q=q[1].split("&");
     var str=""
     for(i=0;i<q.length;i++){
       tmp=q[i].split("=")
       str+=" "+tmp[1]+"<br />"
                                      }
     document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=str
                  }
     onload=function(){
       getQuerystring()
                 }
</script>
```

Then I can call the value of 'name' using id="name" where I want to use this on my page, i.e. in the heading, I could say, *Phil*, looking forward to having you at the party...

That's working well.  The problem I have is, I have a Form I'm using as well, and within that, it has a Placeholder field, like so;

```
<div class="form-section">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="validate-required" placeholder="Names">
```

How can I insert my 'id' value of 'name' into my placeholder here?  The end result would be, the invite mechanic would work on the same URL, across multiple invitees, but the URL would just change.  The RSVP form would reflect what is in the URL as the placeholder, yet the user could still update it if it was incorrect.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. So you want to change the value of `placeholder` of whatever value you get from the function? if so can you use `document.getElementById("foo").placeholder = "foo"` for that ?

Comment: see my answer and mark as right it solves your question.

Comment: Thanks Otávio, your suggestion solved the challenge for me!

Comment: You are welcome! Good Luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This find placeholder and change using jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#name').attr("placeholder", "your place holder here");
    });
</script>
```

if it's a $var also don't need quotes would be like

```
$('#name').attr("placeholder", $str);
```

Or using javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function getQuerystring(){
         var q=document.location.toString();
         q=q.split("?");
         q=q[1].split("&");
         var str=""
         for(i=0;i<q.length;i++){
             tmp=q[i].split("=");
             str+=" "+tmp[1]+"<br />";
         }
         document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=str;
         document.getElementById("name").placeholder=str;
     }
     onload=function(){
         getQuerystring();
     };
</script>
```

`document.getElementById("name").placeholder="value here"` if it's a var so don't need quotes

Also **you need to insert an id to your html input field**

```
<div class="form-section">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="validate-required" placeholder="Names">
```

Comment: jQuery is overkill for just this one use and he does not say he is using it. Still a correct answer though.

Comment: You are right but the jquery is much less code to do the same thing. anyway that's why I also made a javascript version.

Comment: Fair points indeed. And jQuery is very reliable and useful, I just wish it meshed better with built in arrays and what not.

Comment: Can you wrap the code in an IIFE? Anyway, good answer: Upvoted

Comment: Yes I will do that

Comment: +1 but there are lots of ways to select an element without having an `id` on it, so you don't **_need_ to insert** one. Try `document.querySelector('input[name="name"]')`

Comment: Yeah I just warned him that his code was missing an id in case he was using something more in this attribute